# Origen de la expresión "a gatas"

Tags: etimología, expresiones, historia, animales

Tratando de buscar el origen de la expresión *[a gatas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0DlL8w)* ("dicho de ponerse o andar una persona: con pies y manos en el suelo, como los gatos y demás cuadrúpedos"), me encuentro con que me estoy metiendo en un [berenjenal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5NIOz0T). Por un lado, en el diccionario español-italiano de Casas (1570) ya aparece la expresión "a gatas". Así que me fui al CORDE y me encuentro con:

> Pues viéndose el Maestre en tan mala fortuna, fuése **a gatas** llevando arrastrando las cadenas hasta un adarve por donde se había de volver a echar.
>
> - Alonso Maldonado, "Hechos del Maestre de Alcántara don Alonso de Monroy", España (c. 1492)

Y más atrás aún:

> Et porque non pudie yr derecho començo a yr por tierra de pies et de manos **a gatas**.
>
> - Alfonso X, "General Estoria. Cuarta parte.", España (c. 1280)

Vamos, que llegué hasta el siglo XIII y ahí seguía la expresión. Así pues, ¿alguien sabe hasta dónde se remonta? ¿Es posible que provenga del latín? Y ya para rematar, dado que la definición dice "como los gatos y demás cuadrúpedos": ¿es posible saber por qué se escogió al gato como símil y no a otro animal?

Comment: Eso es más viejo que "andar a gatas"...

Comment: Interesante que el verbo [gatear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0GaP9q) se refiera a esta expresión.

Comment: NB gattonare (IT), gatejar (CA).

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente proviene de Grecia:

> **Llevarse el gato al agua**
>
> El gato de esta expresión es una forma metafórica de indicar cómo se
>   dejaba al adversario tras un ejercicio de resistencia y fuerza (a
>   cuatro patas, o lo que es lo mismo… a gatas) y que ya se practicaba en
>   la Antigua Grecia.
>
> En sus inicios, este ejercicio se realizaba en las instrucciones
>   militares y con los años ha acabado convirtiéndose es el famoso juego
>   llamado ‘tira y afloja’, el cual consiste en que dos grupos
>   contrincantes tiran cada uno desde una extremidad, hasta
>   tumbar/arrastrar unos a los otros.
>
> En sus orígenes se realizaba teniendo un charco o rio de por medio y
>   ganaba aquel equipo que lograba lanzar al suelo y arrastrar a sus
>   contrincantes hacia el terreno de ellos, cruzando la línea divisoria
>   que marcaba el agua. De ahí que quedasen **a gatas**.

Referencia: ["El origen de algunas expresiones que nombran un animal y que nada tienen que ver con animales"](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/tag/andar-a-gatas/), Alfred López (02/07/2016)

Answer (score 1):

Lo mio es puramente conjetural en cuanto al origen. Arriesgaría que siendo el "gatear" la primera locomoción que logramos en el desarrollo psico-motriz, hasta alcanzar la habilidad de movernos verticalmente como la especie bípeda que somos —los bebés se movilizan en  cuatro patas, "a gatas" desde alrededor de los 4 meses hasta pasado el año de crecimiento—, **es probable que la asignación del acto de desplazarse tempranamente por el suelo de esa forma haya sido hecha en relación al gato, dada la proporción relativa de estos con nuestros cachorros humanos**. Si bien la mayoría de los mamíferos son cuadrúpedos, tiene sentido haber designado esa acción con la que hace una especie de porte equivalente, como son los gatos, [domesticada desde hace aproximadamente diez mil años](https://www.agenciasinc.es/Noticias/Asi-se-convirtio-el-gato-en-el-animal-domestico-que-conocemos-hoy)

Adicionalmente quisiera señalar que la expresión "a gatas" es usada frecuentemente en castellano para designar algo hecho con dificultad, apenas logrado, connotando siempre una consecución afortunada o penosa debido a un fuerte impedimento de energía, fuerza o habilidad.